# Post XML or JSON to FHIR API Server

Tags: json, xml, curl, hl7-fhir

I am working on a medical application based on HL7 FHIR. I am trying to add new record using XML and JSON both. But all I get is the '500 Internal Server Error'.
The XML I am trying to POST is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <title>Patient Data</title>
   <id>urn:uuid:20</id>
   <updated>2015-05-21T16:33:58.030533</updated>
   <entry>
      <title>Patient Dummy Data</title>
      <id>Other/p21-disease-activity-score-1439917023</id>
      <updated>2015-08-18T18:57:03</updated>
      <published>2015-08-18T18:57:03</published>
      <content type="text/xml">
         <Other xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <identifier>
               <value value="p21-disease-activity-score-1439917023" />
            </identifier>
            <text>
               <status value="generated" />
            </text>
            <subject>
               <reference value="patient/21" />
               <display value="4" />
            </subject>
            <code>
               <coding>
                  <system value="http://hl7.org/fhir/other-resource-type" />
                  <code value="RA_DISEASE_ACTIVITY" />
               </coding>
            </code>
         </Other>
      </content>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

I am posting this XML to API Server using PHP-CURL but getting 500 Internal Server Error.

I tried with JSON too but no luck. Here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "resourceType": "Bundle",
        "title": "PatientData",
        "id": "urn:uuid:21",
        "updated": "2015-05-21T16:33:58.030533",
        "entry": [
            {
                "title": "MyTitle",
                "id": "Other/p007-shoulder-lt-1439220540",
                "updated": "2015-08-10T11:29:00",
                "published": "2015-08-10T11:29:00",
                "author": {
                    "name": "Medtak"
                },
                "content": {
                    "resourceType": "Other",
                    "identifier": "007",
                    "text": {
                        "status": "generated"
                    },
                    "subject": {
                        "reference": "patient/007",
                        "display": "true"
                    },
                    "code": {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/other-resource-type",
                                "code": "RA_DISEASE_ACTIVITY"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have spent almost 3 days to fix this issue but couldn't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tired so for 3days can we get some samples

Comment: Why would I need to convert XML to JSON?

Comment: I have tried to POST XML File using Curl to the API Server. Also I tried with JSON too.

Comment: Which server did you post to, and what address? please try using one of the public servers

Answer (score 3):

POST a resource via CURL

```
curl -X POST https://api.1uphealth.care/fhir/stu2/Patient \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx_your_access_token_here_xxx" \
  -d '{"resourceType": "Patient","id": "helloiamatestpatient","gender": "female"}'
```

If you're posting xml, use the correct xml fhir doc and change the `Content-Type`.

Depending on the FHIR server you're working with, you may not be able to POST resources because many do not support write access yet.

Here's some more information on [using oauth to query FHIR - https://1up.health/dev/intro-fhir-api-oauth-query](https://1up.health/dev/intro-fhir-api-oauth-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea if you following below link.
http://hl7-fhir.github.io/overview-dev.html